# XRDP credentials stopped working, XRDP login failed for display 0

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp

My credentials worked up until yesterday, now it gives me xrdp session: Login failed for display 0. But trying the same credentials out on the terminal works.

```
user1:~-$ su - user1
Password:
user1:~-$
```

I tested the service status to see if it`s working

```
user1:~-$ sudo service xrdp status
* xrdp-sesman is running
* xrdp is running
```

This is the log I`m getting in the xrdp

```
user1:~-$ sudo tail -f /var/log/xrdp.log
[20230422-15:14:49] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20230422-15:14:49] [INFO ] sesman connect ok
[20230422-15:14:49] [INFO ] sending login info to session manager, please wait...
[20230422-15:14:49] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login failed for display 0
[20230422-15:14:49] [INFO ] login failed for display 0
[20230422-15:14:54] [ERROR] xrdp_sec_recv: xrdp_mcs_recv failed
[20230422-15:14:54] [ERROR] xrdp_rdp_recv: xrdp_sec_recv failed
[20230422-15:14:54] [ERROR] libxrdp_process_data: xrdp_rdp_recv failed
[20230422-15:14:54] [ERROR] xrdp_process_data_in: xrdp_process_loop failed
```

Weird thing is that it worked up until yesterday and I have been using it for several months now. No clue what`s going on.

Comment: I use XRDP to log into various Linux systems.  Restart the target system, enable XRDP  with sudo systemctl enable xrdp and then log off the active session. This works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me. Tried even to completely clean install it again and nothing.

Comment: I don't know then.  I have used XRDP on several systems without issue.